# Run Batch File On Start-up

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, startup

Is there a way to start multiple programs in a batch file on system start-up? In addition to that, in that batch file, I would like to be able to say: Once I execute a program, wait until that program completely loads, and execute the next listed program.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is better placed on SuperUser. Anyway startup applications are both in registry and a _special folder_. Your second question is more complex: you need some help from the program you want to run (is it interactive? it'll execute and return immediately?)

Comment: My plan was to disable loading any startup items (in the system configuration), and only load system services. Then replace that system function with a batch file that loads all the startup items. I do not know if it would work any better, but I thought I might test it, to see if things still load as slowly (at startup). None of the programs I would be loading require any interactivity.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I had the same issue in Win7 regarding running a script (.bat) at startup (When the computer boots vs when someone logs in) that would modify the network parameters using netsh. What ended up working for me was the following:

1. Log in with an Administrator account
2. Click on start and type “Task Scheduler” and hit return
3. Click on “Task Scheduler Library”
4. Click on “Create New Task” on the right hand side of the screen and set the parameters as follows:

   a. Set the user account to SYSTEM

   b. Choose "Run with highest privileges"

   c. Choose the OS for Windows7
5. Click on “Triggers” tab and then click on “New…”
   Choose “At Startup” from the drop down menu, click Enabled and hit OK
6. Click on the “Actions tab” and then click on “New…”
   If you are running a .bat file use cmd as the program the put 
   /c  .bat
   In the Add arguments field
7. Click on “OK” then on “OK” on the create task panel and it will now
   be scheduled.
8. Add the .bat script to the place specified in your task event.
9. Enjoy.

Comment: Just for practical knowledge, You can even add a task schdeuler entry with a batch file.

Comment: thank you, it's just that I just pointed to the actual batch file on the "actions tab" and it worked. [+1}

Answer (score 99):

To run a batch file at start up: **start >> all programs >> right-click startup >> open >> right click batch file >> create shortcut >> drag shortcut to startup folder**.

The path to the folder is : `[D|C]:\Profiles\{User}\‌​AppData\Roaming\Micro‌​soft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startu‌​p`

Comment: That is a simple and fast solution. It is useful if you want only to solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by **startup folder**?  Is it in `Win/System32` directory?

Comment: Nope, in `D:\Profiles\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: win + r, type "shell:startup"

Comment: Weird that a bat file directly there doesn't work and I had to come here to learn it seems to need to be a shortcut XD. Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: the steps are not clear. what do you mean by "start >> all programs >> right-click startup "

Comment: I believe this solution will only run once the particular {User} logs in.  The original question was on system start-up not on user log in.

Comment: I used this path `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: on a virtual machine, this doesnt work untill you log in with remote desktop

Answer (score 48):

Go to Run **(WINDOWS + R)** and 
Type
**shell:startup**, paste your .bat file there !

Comment: nice! How did I not know that?!+

Comment: This is awesome! Alright, if you have options to pass in the bat file, first create a link to the bat file, second edit the link and add the options in Target.

Comment: on a virtual machine, this doesnt work untill you log in with remote desktop

Answer (score 25):

To start the batch file at the start of your system, you can also use a registry key.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Here you can create a string. As name you can choose anything and the data is the full path to your file.

There is also the registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

to run something at only the next start of your system.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few ways to run a batch file on start up. The one I usually use is through task scheduler. If you press the windows key then type task scheduler it will come up as an option (or find through administerative tools).

When you create a new task you can chose from trigger options such as 'At log on' for a specific user, on workstation unlock etc. Then in actions you select start a program and put the full path to your batch script (there is also an option to put any command line args required).

Here is a an example script to launch Stack Overflow in Firefox:

```
@echo off

title Auto launch Stack Overflow


start firefox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+sql+or+sqlite+or+plsql+or+oracle+or+windows-7+or+cmd+or+excel+or+access+or+vba+or+excel-vba+or+access-vba?sort=newest

REM Optional - I tend to log these sorts of events so that you can see what has happened afterwards
echo %date% %time%, %computername% >> %logs%\StackOverflowAuto.csv

exit
```

Comment: That is an elegant and powerful solution. It is very useful if you like to improve your technical skills.

Answer (score 3):

### RunOnce

[RunOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) is an option and have a few keys that can be used for pointing a command to start on startup (depending if it concerns a user or the whole system):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

setting the value:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v MyBat /D "!C:\mybat.bat"
```

With setting and exclamation mark at the beginning and if the script exist with a value different than 0 the registry key wont be deleted and the script will be executed every time on startup

### SCHTASKS

You can use [SCHTASKS](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) and a triggering event:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONEVENT /MO ONLOGON /TN ON_LOGON /tr "c:\some.bat"
```

or

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONEVENT /MO ONSTART/TN ON_START /tr "c:\some.bat"
```

### Startup Folder

You also have two startup folders - one for the current user and one global.
There you can copy your scripts (or shortcuts) in order to start a file on startup

```
::the global one
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
::for the current user
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: unable to find this folder in Win7 `%WINDIR%\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

Comment: @djacob - try with %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Copy the following lines to Notepad.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\toto\your_file.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**Note:** Replace the batch file name/path accordingly in the script according to your requirement.

**2.** Save the file with .VBS extension, example launch_bat.vbs

**3.** Create new .bat file, in our case **your_file.bat**

**4.** Write the content of your .bat file.
Example:

```
 @echo off
    php c:\laragon\www\my_app\artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000
```

**5.** Run your_file.bat and ejoy :)

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows language is different from English, you can launch the Task Scheduler by

1. Press **Windows+X**
2. Select your language translation of "Computer Management"
3. Follow the instruction in the answer provided by prankin

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to run the batch file as a service, and set the startup of the service to "*Automatic*" or "*Automatic (Delayed Start)*".
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service) for more information on how to do it, personally I like NSSM the most.