# How to call JavaScript(.JS) file in system startup

Tags: javascript

I have one JavaScript(.JS) file and i want to call it when system(PC) is start up.

Is it possible to call JavaScript file whenever system(PC) starts ?

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to execute something when Windows starts.  Firstly, can you execute the file normally by simply double-clicking it?

Comment: What are you intending to achieve by doing this? It would be helpful if you could describe your use case. Are you referring to a .js file on a server or a desktop? What operating system?

Comment: On what Operating system?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks i want to open the popup in browser when system starts. I want this on desktop and OS will be windows

Comment: @jcubic on windows OS

Answer (score 1):

You need an **environnement** to start your JS file. Let's say you use node.

Create a **batch file** (windows) (or sh file (unix)) with something like `node YOURJSFILE.js`.

Then you have to say to your OS to execute it at startup.

**Example : Windows**

> To run a batch file at start up: start >> all programs >> right-click
>   startup >> open >> right click batch file >> create shortcut >> drag
>   shortcut to startup folder.

[Run Batch File On Start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up)

**Example : Unix**

[How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Comment: its open .JS file in editor , like in my case its opening it in Visual Studio. I want to execute the script and not just opening it