# Run Azure Storage Emulator as service

Tags: windows, azure, windows-services, azure-storage-emulator

We use Azure Storage Emulator on the development machines and the CI server to be able to use storage queues locally. Now every time I sign out of Windows or reboot, I need to start the storage emulator manually.

**Is there a way to start the Azure storage emulator as service, so that it automatically starts when Windows does?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Updated answer after trying out options from Gaurav Mantris answer

Running the batch file as described by Gaurav Mantri keeps the command window open. Here is a way to avoid that:

- Open Task Scheduler
- Create a new task
- Add the "At log on" trigger
- Add a "Start a program" action with the following settings:

  - Program/Script: `AzureStorageEmulator.exe`
  - Add arguments: `start`
  - Start in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator` (or wherever the storage emulator resides on your disk)

Comment: This still requires you to login to the server, were you able to set it up like a standard Windows Service and not have to login?

Answer (score 5):

Storage Emulator files can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator`. I noticed a batch file in there called `StartStorageEmulator.cmd`.

What you could is create a shortcut of this file in your `Startup` folder (e.g. `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`). Then when you login back again, the storage emulator will start automatically. [Please see instructions here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/28206/windows-8-how-to-add-applications-startup-folder/].

Other alternative is to create a new task that runs this batch file and schedule that task to run when computer starts. Please see this thread for more details: [Run Batch File On Start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up).

Answer (score 5):

One option to run any non-service process, such as a console application, as a service is to use the [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc) as the host. (Historically you might have used `SRVANY.EXE` from the Windows NT Resource Kit.)

Using NSSM it's as simple as:

```
> choco install nssm -y
> nssm install AzureStorageEmulator "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" start -inprocess
```

Comment: This surely worked under the emulator version at the time, but unfortunately it's not working today. The service starts and the process stays in memory, but the emulator reports a status of not running at the command line and returns a 500 server error to the browser. Shucks. I had high hopes for this one.

Comment: I just read Orangutech's post below, and it seems to be a good solution. I'll try it later today and report the results back here.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working as a service (same problem, even after the db trick from Orangutech), so I did the next best thing: ran it as a scheduled task, every hour on the hour. Turns out it doesn't hurt anything to run `AzureStorageEmulator start -inprocess` while it's already listening—it just spits out an error message to the console, that's all.

Comment: FYI I'm running the scheduled task under SYSTEM. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

On our AX "OneBox" dev environments, there was already a scheduled task `DynamicsStartAzureStorageEmulator` that launches the emulator as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM on startup. Azure Storage Emulator was upgraded (Automatically? By the devs?), and then it stopped working.

The issue was twofold:

1. It was trying to use the LocalDB(SQL Express Subset) instance
2. It needed to initialize a new DB, as SYSTEM.

(Example, before it was `AzureStorageEmulatorDB49`, now it's `AzureStorageEmulatorDB510`)

Once I ran a shell/cmd as SYSTEM (using PSEXEC, and tried to run the emulator to see the error output, the rest was pretty straightforward.

The solution was pretty much just: Run shell as system (Using Psexec)

```
PsExec.exe -i -s cmd
```

And as SYSTEM, init the new database (in our case, using "Real" SQL, rather than LocalDB/Express.):

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -server localhost
```

(If you want to stick w/ LocalDB, `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init` should work just fine)

As it was multiple VMs, I used powershell remoting:

```
$ListOfHostnames | foreach {.\PsExec.exe \\$_ -i -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe" init -server localhost}
```

(Yes, if you have PwSH 7, you can use -parallel ;)

After that, it was a simple reboot to verify it all came up automatically.

Additional items:
I set the scheduled task to also just start once a day at like 5 am, just in case it wasn't running for some reason.

Some envs had an emulator DB on the LocalDB instance, which I deleted. Not strictly necessary, just cleaner.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#initialize-the-storage-emulator-to-use-a-different-sql-database and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#command-line-syntax