# How can a PowerShell script be automatically run on startup?

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I want to run my script at boot up time in windows 7

I tried

1. Setup a scheduled task to run at startup -  it doesn't run until someone logs in.
2. Local GP to run script at startup - it doesn't run until someone logs in.
3. Adding the scheduled task from a command prompt with admin - some time work some time not
   schtasks /create /tn "start" /sc onstart /delay 0000:30 /rl highest /ru system /tr "powershell.exe -file <>

any other method to this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Batch File On Start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up)

Comment: This is more likely to be a superuser related question than a StackOverflow related one. (?)

Answer (score 0):

you can make an bat file in your startup folder.

startup.bat whit this content

```
Powershell -command "& {c:\Temp\Test.ps1}"
```