# how to start the batch file automatically when the system restarts

Tags: batch-file

I have three batch files which start services of kibana (in windows). How can I start all the batch files automatically when the system is restarted.

The command to run the bat files are

```
path\elasticsearch-5.5.2\bin>elasticsearch

path\logstash>bin\logstash -f Couchdb_to_elasticsearch.conf

path\kibana-5.5.2-windows-x86\bin>kibana.bat
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Batch File On Start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up)

Comment: Would not say so; this requests on *restart* specifically after my understanding

Comment: You might be able to get something from the eventlog. The powershell provides the command `get-eventlog` to query it (which then can be used from the bacth-file). I tried to find something about the relevant codes but could not find anything quickly. You will surely have more luck :)

Comment: If those batch files really start __services__, why are the services not configured to be automatically started by system?