# Java - setting a batch file to run on startup

Tags: java, batch-file, set, startup

I'm wondering if there's any way to [set an existing batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up) to run on windows startup from within Java code.
If not using Java, perhaps another language?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218346/run-batch-file-on-start-up

Comment: this is a completely different question...

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the file inside
    C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup 
A faster way to find it is using windos key + r -> then type shell:startup